# Show custom location with pin on Map with MapKit (Swift)

Tags: swift, annotations, location, mkmapview

I am trying to create a view for in my app which shows the location of a restaurant. When the user enters the view, it shows something like this [image]

But instead shows the location of the restaurant with a pin and a more zoomed in view. I am new to MapKit and have not been able to make any progress.

This is what my view consists of.
[image]

And this is what my view controller consists of.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class FD1ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Comment: this is a too broad question , you need to read a tutorial before this implementation may this https://www.raywenderlich.com/548-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started or https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/19/2/up-and-running-with-mapkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class FD1ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      //Create the pin location of your restaurant(you need the GPS coordinates for this)
      let restaurantLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 111.0, longitude: 111.0)

      //Center the map on the place location
      mapView.setCenter(restaurantLocation, animated: true)
   }

}
```

This should do it. I hope it helps!